# wcf data service with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am trying to create WCF Data service project using Entity Framework. ( I am new to both).

I created entities using DB.
Now, I created service operation, which returns the `IQueryable<entity>`.

My problem is

1. I do not want to return the entire set of  columns in the entity. I cannot delete them from the entity as it is not null. How to avoid these?
2. I have few FK columns and I need other column details of the table. How to include columns from other table?
3. Why it is not possible to use POCO class to be returned from WCF Data service?
4. How do I format the response; i.e., add few more details to the response like page number etc, change the xml tags, remove few details like "link rel"?

I have tried a lot of things to achieve 1 and 2. But finally I realised that I can only use the entity as it is to make it work.

I have no idea about 4.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. I do not want to return the entire set of columns in the entity.*
>   *2. I have few FK columns and I need other column details of the
>   table.*

For this, you should define a new class that matches what you need / what you want your clients to see. That can be a straight POCO class - no special requirements. Assemble that class for each entity, leaving out the unwanted columns, and grabbing the extra field or two for the FK columns into that new class. Return an `IQueryable<YourNewClass>` instead of the entity class directly.

To avoid huge left-right-assignment statements just to fill the properties of the new class, you should have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) which makes it really easy to copy around classes that are very similar to one another (e.g. missing or adding a few properties).

> *4. How do I format the response; i.e., add few more details to the
>   response like page number etc, change the xml tags, remove few details
>   like "link rel"?*

That's not possible - the OData protocol very strictly defines what's going to be in the message, what links there are etc. If you can't live with that - you'll have to roll your own WCF REST service and drop the WCF Data Service stuff altogether.

Check out the [WCF REST Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) if you want to investigate that route more thoroughly.

**Update:** that link seems to have gone dead - try [WCF Web Http Programming Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412169.aspx) instead.

Comment: I am doing what you suggested for point 1 and 2, I am getting error "The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'On data context type 'GamesContext', there is a top IQueryable property 'Games' whose element type is not an entity type. Make sure that the IQueryable property is of entity type or specify the IgnoreProperties attribute on the data context type to ignore this property.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: " Followed this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg601461

Comment: @Priya10: seems to be a [known issue with a few workarounds](http://samuelmueller.com/2009/11/working-with-projections-and-dtos-in-wcf-data-services/) - hope this might help you!

Comment: @marc_s that link seems to be dead, and I'm getting that error

Comment: @Maslow: yup, link seems dead - I added a new link, have a look there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an `Id` property or you specify either `[Key]` or `[DataServiceKey("Your_Custom_ID_Property")]`
For me this sorted out the issue